# Changing Order of Columns Only On Tablet Portrait and Landscape

Tags: bootstrap-4

Trying to use the doer class with boot strap to change the order of the 3r and 4th column on this site but can't figure it out.

Red Bud and Waterloo Locations need to be swapped on Tablet because I have them set for 2 columns on tablet and thee is then no separation between the locations on tablet. its one long dark column and one long white column

[Website here][1]
https://tequilamex.com/order-online/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class `order-first order-md-2` to the third div `padding-0 dark center-all col-small-12 col-md-push-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xl-3`

It'll change the order on mobile/tablet only. On the documentation there's more info https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Here's a codeply showing different orders
https://www.codeply.com/p/tOg36wji73